# Recursively output a new array?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, insert, return

Oddly enough I didn't find ANY information about this over the whole internet. For a homework assignment, of course.., I have to recursively add an element to its rightful place in an already-sorted array. Problem is - as arrays in java have a fixed size I cannot change my current array so I have to make a new one. That would be easy without recursion but the following code doesn't work for obvious reasons:

```
static int[] recursivelyInsertElement(int[] array, int index, boolean isAdded, int elem) {

    // Takes a sorted array with index = 0 (because.... recursion), an element
    // we'd like to insert and a boolean (default: false) to prevent us from
    // inserting the element more than once. 

    int[] newArray = new int[array.length + 1];

    if (index >= array.length && isAdded) {
        return newArray;
    }

    if (index >= array.length && !isAdded){
        newArray[index] = elem;
        return newArray;
    }

    if (array[index] > elem && !isAdded) {
        newArray[index] = elem;
        isAdded = true;
    }

    newArray[index] = array[index];
    return recursivelyInsertElement(array, index + 1, isAdded, elem);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 45 };

    int elem = 6;

    int[] newArray = recursivelyInsertElement(array, 0, false, elem);

    for (int index = 0; index < newArray.length; index++) {
        System.out.print(newArray[index] + " ");
    }

}


// Expected output: 1 3 5 6 7 9 11 45 
// Actual output: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
// The obvious issue here is that a new array is initialized on every step.
// What I'd like to do is avoid this.
```

So I was wondering - how should I approach this? Make a second function which adds up the elements in a new array? Though I'm pretty sure the goal of the assignment is for my `recursivelyInsertElement()` to return the new array itself.

P.S. I'd appreciate if you gave me just advives and tips, not whole solutions!

Comment: you aren't copying the old array into the new array, or passing the partially constructed new array down in each recursive step

Comment: How am I not doing so? And isn't the main problem here that a new blank array is initialized every single time the funciton is called?

Comment: each invocation of your recursive method creates a new array - and all progress from before in the prior new arrays are lost

Comment: add a comment above as to what each of your method args is, and an example of how your method is invoked and the results you get vs what you expect to get

Comment: @AmirAfghani Done! Editted my OP, including a couple of clarification comments here and there and the `main` method.

Comment: shouldn't your expected output be 1 3 5 6 7 9 11 45 ?

Comment: @AmirAfghani Yes, I corrected myself asap.

Comment: are you trying to return a sorted array? Is that what your program is supposed to do? eg: 1,2,4,5,7,9 and if I want to insert 6 then the output is 1,2,4,5,6,7,9. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: My input array is sorted by default. Therefore, my output array should be sorted as well. And yes, 6, should be inserted inbetween 5 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

So a few pointers...

1. You only need to allocate a new array once - and that is when you
   have found the correct location and are about to insert the new 
   element.
2. When you create the new array you have to copy all the values from
   the old array into the new one, shifting the index of the elements
   greater than the new element up by 1 to leave a space for it.
3. Once you have inserted the new element, you are done and simply
   return the new array all the way up the stack.
4. 1 & 3 combined mean that you never pass the new array to the
   recursive call: you only ever pass the original array in and return the new array (either directly or as a result of recursion).
5. Each recursive call just increases the index - it is guaranteed to
   return at some point.

**If that is enough tips then stop here... !**

So, your main function is fine, and your insert function should be something like:

```
  if index >= array.length
    // run out of array so add to end
    create new array and copy existing data
    add new element at end of array
    return new array

  if array[index] > elem
    // found the first element greater than the candidate so insert before it
    create new array and copy existing data
    add new element at index
    return new array

  // not found so call again with the next index
  return recusrivelyInsertElement(array, index + 1, elem)
```

Note that the `isAdded` flag has gone, as per point 3.

Hope this helps